# The Wug Test For Grownups

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, scrabble

Jean Gleason has invented a brand new test for adults to try, not just kids!

[image: Puzzle content]

Comment: By the way, I accidentally searched and found the answers on reddit. Next time can you try posting your puzzles simultaneously (if you want to post on multiple sites) and inform each site of the other's presence please? Perhaps it'll be a nicer way of bringing the communities together. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: i don't htink it's possible for me to post htem simultaneously given the rules of the other community, but of course i always encourage people to join us over there. anyways idk if spoiling is a problem i might add a disclaimer that these have been posted elsewhere

Answer (score 6):

The [Wug Test](https://scholarshipinstitute.org/what-is-the-wug-test/) is a test to determine how well children can pluralize and conjugate nonsense words, based on their understanding of the language.

This "Wug Test for Grownups" employs a similar methodology.  Each of the clues refers to a made-up word, that nonetheless makes sense based on its roots.

To further confuse things, the letters next to each clue do not correspond to that clue; the letter groups and clues are randomly arranged.

Here are the answers to each clue, formed by rearranging one of the groups of letters provided:

***A revitalized form of a 1980s hiphop genre that pays homage to the Illest Villain (2 wds)***

> **DOOM BAP**
>  - a portmanteau of DOOM (referring to MF Doom, a character created by Illest Villain) and BOOM BAP (a hiphop genre)

***A shape with half a side***

> **SEMIGON**
>  - from SEMI-, meaning half, and POLYGON

***A unit of 10^9 animals***

> **GIGAZOO**
>  - GIGA- is the prefix for 1 billion, or $10^9$, and ZOO

***Alien conversation***

> **XENOLOG**
>  - from XENO-, meaning alien, and LOGOS, meaning word or language

***Dotty, sommwhat like a Signac painting***

> **STIPPLY**
>  - STIPPLE is a series of small dots, like the pointillism used in Signac paintings.  (At least [one dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stipply) claims STIPPLY is a valid English word, but it doesn't seem to appear in others.)

***Having an elevated blood level?***

> **ACREMIA**
>  - from the prefix ACR-, meaning high, and -EMIA, meaning blood-related

***Of or related to stars***

> **ASTERIC**
>  - from the Latin ASTER, meaning star, and the suffix -IC, meaning "of or related to"

***Sunrise-based divination***

> **EOMANCY**
>  - from the prefix EO- (related to dawn) and the suffix -MANCY (method of divination)

It seems clear that these words must each be placed on one of the Scrabble boards shown in order to score the number of points indicated next to the clue, but I have had a lot of trouble getting the correct scores.  I have found several locations where one of the solutions fits perfectly between other words, but doesn't score the number indicated in the clue.

> Example: On the second board on the bottom row, **EOMANCY** fits horizontally between ARTERIAL and DESISTED (beginning above the first D in DESISTED), but it scores 123 points instead of the 110 indicated next to its clue.

I did get two words to score exactly as indicated:

> **STIPPLY** on the bottom-right board, using the Y in STIPPLY to make yOURSELVES
>  **ACREMIA** on the top-right board, using the C and M to make PUSHcHAIR and DECOmPOSE

> I wondered if there was perhaps a further message hidden in the score discrepancies (e.g. if the actual score is 5 more than listed, that could indicate an E (5th letter of the alphabet)), but that seems hard, because if you are not trying to match the score, there are many places you could put the words, resulting in many possible discrepancies.

I have not been successful in matching any other scores.  Perhaps someone else can take up the mantle and finish the job.

Comment: For the blood one, I think it's rot13(NPE-RZVN yvxr npeb-ongvpf naq na-rzvn)

Comment: @caPNCApn Ah, I like that better.  I'll update it.  Thanks.

Comment: I think your E-----Y _does_ fit where you speculate for the total 110 - remember you don't count double/triple word/letter score spaces that are already used in the other side words, only those you are covering on this turn :)

Comment: I got to essentially the same place as you (except that I didn't find an answer for the blood one because some bit of my brain rot13(fhogenpgrq RZVN sebz NNPRVZE naq tbg NNE vafgrnq bs NPE)) and stalled in essentially the same way. It feels as if the next stage in solving has to be some huge exhaustive search, and I just don't have the patience.

Comment: don't see why an exhaustive search has to be necessary. treat this the same way you would a logic puzzle. an average bingo scores about 70 points or so, the points given are well above that

Comment: OED has a first citation for your S—Y word from 1892, fwiw

Comment: @empyreu The problem is finding a place to put the word that provides *exactly* the same number of points as is provided in the clues.  I have found several places that provide *more* points, but I doubt that is the goal of the puzzle.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain read what stiv said and make sure you're counting the points correctly

Comment: In addition to what you and @Stiv found, the following words can be placed in the corresponding grids by also forming the word listed after them: rot13(2. krabybt, rknpg 3. frzvtba, bzvffvba 5. nfgrevp, rnpu 6. tvtnmbb, tebbzvat); not sure where the remaining one goes in the first grid, but I kinda gave up 